# How do I fix a light switch timer?

Tags: lighting, switch, light-fixture

I have some auto-light switches in my home. The one in the image below has nothing in the LCD display and is non-operational. How do I fix that? Manual operation does not work either.

Below the buttons is what looks like a battery compartment. Gentle prying with a screwdriver was unable to open it.

At the top of the switch is another slide-button. I can move that to the right but not the left. The light doesn't work in either position.

Does anyone recognize the brand of this light switch and if there's an operator's PDF around? (In addition to any ideas on how to fix this...)

The other light switches in the house that are like this operate normally.

[image: light switch]

Comment: If you remove the switch from the box, there should be manufacturer markings on the back/sides of the device. This might help you find documentation on this device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it might be an [EJ500 Astro In-Wall Timer](http://www.intermatic.com/en/Products/Timers/InWallTimers/Electronic_Timers/EJ500.aspx), or similar device. Here's a link to the [Installation Instructions (PDF)](http://www.intermatic.com/~/media/Intermatic/Documentation/Timers/In-Wall/Electronic/EJ351C_and_EJ500/EJ500_Instructions.pdf).

According to the instructions, the switch at the top of the device is an "air gap" switch. Which is "*designed to turn power off for routine maintenance*".

> [image: Air Gap Switch]

You remove the battery holder "*by prying left and right of the holder
with the tip of a flat screwdriver, then pry the battery holder up.*"

> [image: Battery Holder]

There's a another document available, describing the [battery installation/replacement (PDF)](http://www.intermatic.com/~/media/Intermatic/Documentation/Timers/In-Wall/Electronic/EJ351C_and_EJ500/EJ500C_Battery_Replacement_and_Installation.pdf).

I'm not familiar with this device myself, so I'm not sure if it's fixable or if it should simply be replaced. You might try changing the batteries and see if that helps, as the instructions mention changing the batteries if the display is dim.

> - Replace the batteries if the display is dim or displays “lobAT”

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what the part pointed to by the red arrow is for?

[image]

I am not familiar with this unit but the indicated item seems like it could be a catch to allow the control panel unit to be removed from the wall mount.

It is also possible that this could be a manual override switch although this seems more unlikely from looking at the pictures.